# Is wrapping C++ library with ctypes a bad idea?

Tags: python, ctypes, boost-python

I read through the following two threads on [wrapping C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942298/wrapping-a-c-library-in-python-c-cython-or-ctypes) and [C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100554/wrapping-c-dynamic-array-with-pythonctypes-segfault), I am not sure I get it yet. The C++ library I am working with does use class and template, but not in any over-sophisticated way. What are issues or caveats of wrapping it with ctypes (besides the point that you can do so in pure python etc)?

PyCXX , Cython and boost::python are three other choices people mentioned, is there any consensus which one is more suitable for C++?

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For C++ a library to be accessible from Python it must use C export names, which basically means that a function named `foo` will be accessible from ctypes as `foo`.

This can be achieved *only* by enclosing the public interface with `export C {}`, which in turn disallows function overloading and templates therein (only the public interface of the library to be wrapped is relevant, the inner workings are not and may use any C++ features they like).

Reason for this is that C++ compilers use a mechanism called *name mangling* to generate unique names for overloaded or templated symbols. While `ctypes` would still find a function provided you knew its mangled name, the mangling scheme depends on the compiler/linker being used and is nothing you can rely on. *In short: do not use ctypes to wrap libraries that use C++ features in their public interface*.

`Cython` takes a different approach. It aids you at building a C extension module that does the interfacing with the original library. Therefore, linking to the C++ library is done by the regular C++ linkage mechanism, thus avoiding the aforementioned problem. The trouble with Cython is that C extension libraries need to to be recompiled for every platform, but anyway, this applies to the C++ library to be wrapped as well.

Personally, I'd say that in most cases the time to fire up Cython is a time that is well-spent and will eventually pay off in comparison to ctypes (with an exception for really simple Cish interfaces).

I don't have any experience with `boost.python`, so I can't comment on it (however, I don't have the impression that it is very popular either).

Comment: Thanks for bringing up Cython as an option! I picked it for wrapping C api and had a positive experience - it is like writing Python with a few lines of C in it, and gives a lot of control. One thing I had hard time with was getting the build process right - I ended up pre-compiling Cython files before creating source distribution. If anybody has similar problems, I explained in details how I wrapped my C api with Cython here, including the build process: http://martinsosic.com/development/2016/02/08/wrapping-c-library-as-python-module.html

Answer (score 15):

In defence of `boost::python`, given Alexander's answer on ctypes:

Boost python provides a *very* "c++" interface between c++ and python code - even doing things like allowed python subclasses of c++ classes to override virtual methods is relatively straightforward. Here's a potted list of good features:

- Allow virtual methods of C++ classes to be overridden by python subclasses.
- Bridge between `std::vector<>`, `std::map<>` instances and python lists and dictionaries (using `vector_indexing_suite` and `map_indexing_suite`)
- Automatic sharing of reference counts in smart pointers (`boost::shared_ptr`, etc) with  python reference counts (and you can extend this to any smart pointer).
- Fine grained control of ownership when passing arguments and returning values from functions.

Basically, if you have a design where you want to expose a c++ interface in a way faithful to the language, then boost::python is probably the best way to do it.

The only downsides are increased compile time (boost::python makes extensive use of templates), and sometimes opaque error messages if you don't get things quite right.

Comment: The other problem is the strong coupling of boost and python versions. For example, if you upgrade your python version, you will have to rebuild the version of boost